# First day and last of the year

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

Need to compare a date with a first day of the year and last day of the year by linq method

```
c.TERMINATION_DATE < FirstDayofYear (DateTime.Now)
     && c.TERMINATION_DATE > LastDayOfYear(DateTime.Now)
```

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, the first and last days of the year are always the same: January 1st and December 31st:

```
// Only fetch the property *once*, for consistency
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime start = new DateTime(today.Year, 1, 1);
DateTime end = new DateTime(today.Year, 12, 31);

...
// In your LINQ query
where c.TerminationDate < start || c.TerminationDate > end
...
```

Note that I've changed the condition to `||` instead of `&&` - after all, the value can't be before the first day of the year *and* after the last day of the year. If course, it's possible that you've just got your conditions the wrong way.

Also note that if your `TerminationDate` property *actually* stores a date/time rather than just a date, you could have problems - because start/end will both be midnight on the start of their respective dates.

Another thing to consider - and somewhat simpler - is *just* to use the year:

```
int year = DateTime.Today.Year;

...
// In your LINQ query
where c.TerminationDate.Year != year
...
```

Comment: Great Idea mate :) Thanks alot. I am still a beginner in some things and I didn't came with this idea in my mind :) Thanks alot for you solving method.